# React app not sending headers to java server

Tags: java, reactjs, header, authorization, token

I searched a lot on the Internet, but I didn't find anything helpful for my problem. 
I have a java server and a react client. My server is using jwt for authentication and returns a token to my client.

When I try to send data with a post method, my client does not send the headers, so my server returns an "Unauthorized" message. I tried to send the same request from Postman and ARC(Advanced Rest Client) and it works.

Here is my client code:

```
fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'token generated from fiddler after running auth',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson => {
                console.log(responseJson);
            });
```

I tried using axios too and I have the same problem. 
Also my server has @CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"}) annotation in all controller classes.

I don't know if my problem is with the client or with the server and why is working using Postman and ARC.

Comment: why are you using `mode: 'no-cors'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mode: no-cors` which basically strips out all headers which are not simple headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

You should enable CORS and allow your domain on the server.

Comment: I changed mode in ```cors``` and I'm still not receiving the header.

Comment: Did you enable cors on the backend? You don't need to set the mode to cors, just don't set it to no-cors. What is the request in the network tab? What do you receive on the backend?

Comment: Thank you, I delete the mode setting and now worked. I am sorry for late answer, but just today I was able to configure it.